# How can CREATE OR REPLACE fail with already exists?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, ddl

`DETAIL:  Key (proname, proargtypes, pronamespace)=(rand, , 2200) already exists.: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "rand"() RETURNS float AS`

How on earth is that even possible? How can `CREATE OR REPLACE` fail with already exists? This is in a docker container, completely pristine environment and this is the only that code runs. Yes, it might run repeatedly but that's why the `OR REPLACE`is there. I do not get it. Here's the full command:

```
  if (!$connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'rand'")->fetchField()) {
    $connection->query('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "rand"() RETURNS float AS
      \'SELECT random();\'
      LANGUAGE \'sql\'');
  }
```

Comment: Concurrent executions of this code may lead to the error mentioned. Are you sure there's only one database session that runs this at any point in time?

Comment: Sorry, I have formulated the situation wrong -- yes, it might run in parallel. But they are not in a transaction as far as I can see. So  `CREATE OR REPLACE` has a race condition in it? Is there documentation on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OR REPLACE` clause in `CREATE FUNCTION` is not meant for seamless parallel execution, it's meant to avoid dropping the function when we just want to update the body. From [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html):

> If you drop and then recreate a function, the new function is not the
>   same entity as the old; you will have to drop existing rules, views,
>   triggers, etc. that refer to the old function. Use CREATE OR REPLACE
>   FUNCTION to change a function definition without breaking objects that
>   refer to the function.

Now if several sessions issue the same `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` in parallel, there is indeed a potential race condition that is dealt with by relying on the unique index on `(proname, proargtypes, pronamespace)`, and comes back to the caller as an error.

The error mentioned in the question happens if, for instance:

- session #1 starts `CREATE OR REPLACE` and finds the function does not exist, so it creates it, inserting into `pg_proc` and locking the corresponding `(proname, proargtypes, pronamespace)` entry in the index.
- session #2 starts `CREATE OR REPLACE`, finds the function does not exist (because #1 has not committed yet) and is put to wait for the index lock.
- session #1 commits.
- session #2 tries to insert and fails.

Note that not using explicit BEGIN/COMMIT does not change the race condition: the BEGIN/COMMIT pairs are just implicit around each SQL statement.

To have this parallel sequence work seamlessly, `OR REPLACE` would need to be to `CREATE FUNCTION` what `ON CONFLICT` is to `INSERT`, but that's not the case.

To deal with conflicting or identical DDL that might run in parallel, probably you should use an explicit lock at the beginning of the sequence to put it as a whole in a critical section. [Advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) might be used for that. Or you need to implement a "retry on failure" strategy with savepoints around individual statements.